# Uno NavigationBar not displaying label

Tags: uinavigationbar, uno

I am using UNO NavigationBar for a windows and WASM app. This is the code:

```
<utu:NavigationBar x:Name="navBar" Background="{StaticResource NavigatorBkgColor}" 
        Content="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}" MainCommandMode="Action" >
    <utu:NavigationBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Label="Locations" uen:Navigation.Request="Locations" Foreground="White">
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Project/Assets/Icons/location_chip.png"/>
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
        </AppBarButton>
        <AppBarButton Label="Login" uen:Navigation.Request="Login" Foreground="White">
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Project/Assets/Icons/login.png"/>
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
        </AppBarButton>
    </utu:NavigationBar.PrimaryCommands>
    <utu:NavigationBar.SecondaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Label="Profile" Command="{Binding ProfileCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoggedIn}" />
        <AppBarButton Label="Exit App" Command="{Binding ExitAppCommand}"  />
    </utu:NavigationBar.SecondaryCommands>
</utu:NavigationBar>
```

The problem is that the ICON appears in the bar, but not the Label. The Icons also appear pretty small, is there a way to increase the size?
Using Uno.Extensions 2.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with it, I decided to just forego the feature and create my own navigation bar using stackpanels and buttons.